# New custom form places labels on form fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I'm not sure what was toggled but now when I make custom forms, my form fields have labels stuck on them.
How do I remove them please?

[image]

How do I remove the "change valid" label and the box around the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I believe an Information Management Policy has been set. This feature can be enabled or disabled by the site admin. If you want to read more about it, here is some resources:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-features-of-an-information-management-policy-5e9cf721-ea4c-4c9a-b23d-956bbb368d1a#bmlabels

Comment: Hello Ahmed, I had checked that out but I'm not certain it;s the same thing?

Comment: I have never seen this on a SharePoint list before, the only way I can think of is that either it is done by a 3rd party tool, or the my initial assumption which is the Information Management Policy . Anything 3rd party tool was installed lately on your environment?